# Missing dependency for Musique 1.4 (libtag1c2a)

Tags: software-installation

I want to install the latest version of this program. The appstore version is an older version, 1.1. I have tried installing using gdebi but it has the following error:

E: musique: missing-dependency-on-libc needed by usr/local/bin/musique

I tried installing the missing dependency, libtag1c2a, in terminal but it didn't work.

Has anyone else tried to install this?